# HTML CSS wrap li with ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to wrap multiple `li` in `ul` and horizontally center them in a `div`. It works when there is only 1 row of `li`s but from the second row, the gap appears on the right.

How do I fix this problem?

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="box">
  something
</div>

  <div id="content">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#content {
  display: inline-block;
}

#content ul {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#content li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

[image: example]

this is when there is only 1 row and it is perfect.

[image: example 2]

but from the second row, the width of `ul` expends and the gap on the right appears.

**DEMO**

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zv038tgr/)

**UPDATE**

if this cannot be done with CSS, how do I achieve it with Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: This cannot be done with CSS alone. You will not JS to calculate and set the width of the `#content ul` element.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli will you be able to show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in a comment, it is impossible to do with CSS alone.

Here is a jQuery implementation of calculating how many items fit and setting the width manually

```
$(function(){
    var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
        content = $('#content ul'),
        extras = content.outerWidth() - content.width();

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var wrapperWidth = wrapper.width(),
            children = content.children(),
            itemWidth = children.outerWidth(true),
            fit = Math.floor( (wrapperWidth-extras)/itemWidth );

        content.width( Math.min(fit,children.length) * itemWidth );

    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zv038tgr/7/

Comment: this works perfectly but when I click on the link that is linked to the page that contains this code, it shows the gap on the right again. I got rid of `$(window).on('resize'...` and place the rest of the code directly into `$( document ).ready(function() { ...` but it still does not work

Comment: @H.Kim can you post Live version of your page? Also try using `jQuery` instead of `$` in case `noConflict` is used. Finally check the console for errors.